# How can I download files from database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a FileController with an `addAction` method, which stores one or more files in my database :

```
$files = [];

$form = $this->createForm(MultipleFilesType::class, []);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $files = $form->get("files")->getData();


    foreach ($files as $key => $file)
    {
        /* @var $uploadedFile UploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $file["file"];

        if ($uploadedFile->getError()) {
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('warning', $uploadedFile->getErrorMessage());
        } else {

            $file = (new File())
                    ->setName($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName())
                    ->setContent(file_get_contents($uploadedFile->getPathname()))
                    ->setType($uploadedFile->guessExtension())
            ;

            $this->manager()->persist($file);
            $this->manager()->flush();


        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then I have a `downloadAction`:

```
public function _downloadAction($file, Request $request) 
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($file->getContent());

    $d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\. ]/', "", $file->getName()) 
    );

    $response->headers->set("Content-Type", $file->getType());
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);

    return $response; 
}
```

So I tried with all the code above. My files seem to upload just fine, but when I try to download, I'm facing some issues depending of the type of file.

HTML and EML files work fine.
Microsoft office type files (odt, xml, etc) : can't open them because they are corrupt.
Image files: I get a "This is not a XX type file, file start with 0xc3 0xbf"

So... What is wrong in my code ? Maybe there are some ways I can do that better, but I'm new to file uploading / downloading and I'm struggling quite a bit. 
Also, assume I HAVE TO use database to store the file.

**EDIT :**

I tried a `dump(file_get_contents($uploadedFile->getPathname()));` in the addAction method, and `dump($file->getContent());` in _downloadAction.

The results are very differents (and they shouldn't be !!).
The first dump shows a lot of mysterious characters like : ▓│┤ÁÂÀ©╣║┬├─┼ãÃ╚╔╩ÊËÈıÍÎÏ┘┌ßÔÒõÕµþÞÚÛ±‗¾¶§÷

and the second one uses almost only alphanumerical characters.

I guess I should indeed try to escape characters when I store the content in the database. 
I tried `mysql_escape_string(file_get_contents($uploadedFile->getPathname()))` but it doesn't solve the problem. The original content and the downloaded one are still differents.

Comment: I always store files in disk and use BinaryFileResponse to serve files. Storing files in database is not a good choice from my point of view and I try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Well, the choice of where I should store the files is not up to me.

Comment: Just a guess. But try to make a mysql_real_escape_string() or mysqli_real_escape_string() to your file_get_contents.

Comment: I can't figure how to use mysql_real_escape_string() with symfony2 / doctrine. I get  this error : Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally managed to do it, with a combination of base64_encode() in the addAction method and base64_decode() in the downloadAction method().

Comment: I am facing the same problem. For me I can get the output in console. But its downloading as a file. Any ideas ?